# skipping string having angle brackets <*> in Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a opinion dataset that has some tags in angle brackets not HTML or XML tags. However I want to skip any processing of string that lie between open agle bracket and closed angle bracket. I'm trying to use Regex, any idea for the regular expressions.

EDIT: 
Sample input:

```
<DOC NO> How are you <DOC NO/>
```

want to skip/delete DOC NO & DOC NO/ with angle brackets , and process only "How are you"

Comment: Could you give some particular example?

Comment: What does "skip" mean? Erase them?

Comment: Could you give a sample input, and expected output? And some code showing us what you have tried so far?

Comment: ok "open_angle_bracket"DOC NO"close_angle_bracket" How are you "open_angle_bracket"DOC NO/"close_angle_bracket" . I want to processes on the strings "How are you" and not "DOC NO" as they are between angle brackets. BY skip I mean not to processes them, deletion will also do. PS: cant write angle brackets here in this forum box

Comment: @user3441982: Please edit your question with updates, and use the code formatting, then you can use the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bellow will give you your string without parts that you want to exclude.

```
var cleanedString = Regex.Replace("<DOC NO> How are you <DOC NO/>", "<.*?>", "");
```